# Change levels in factor to numbers with different order in R

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataset that would be similar to the factor below:

```
response = c("Met Expectations", "Exceeded Expectations", "Exceeded    Expectations", "Unacceptable", NA, "Did not meet Expectations" )
factor(response, levels = c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable"))
```

This is what I get for the levels. I have ordered this in the way I get it in the dataset.

```
[1] Met Expectations          Exceeded Expectations     Exceeded Expectations     Unacceptable             
[5] <NA>                      Did not meet Expectations
Levels: Exceeded Expectations Met Expectations Did not meet Expectations Unacceptable
```

I want to convert these levels to numbers. So I tried this:

```
as.numeric(factor(response, levels = c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable")))
```

And I get the correct output:

```
[1]  2  1  1  4 NA  3
```

However I want the order to be 4 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3 4. I am expecting:

```
Exceeding Expectation to be 4
Met Expectations to be 3
Did not meet Expectations to be 2
Unacceptable to be 1
[1] 3  4  4  1  NA  2
```

How can I change the order? Is there a straight forward way to do it else I can modify the numbers after converting them to numeric. In this example I can change the order of the levels parameter and get what I want, but since my dataset gives me the levels in this specific order:

Levels: Exceeded Expectations Met Expectations Did not meet Expectations Unacceptable

I was trying figure out a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the factor, change to `levels = rev(c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable"))`. `rev` will reverse the order of the levels, thereby reversing the order of the numerical values assigned to the category labels.

```
response = c("Met Expectations", "Exceeded Expectations", "Exceeded Expectations", "Unacceptable", NA, "Did not meet Expectations")

response = factor(response, levels = c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable"))

as.numeric(response)

#[1]  2  1  1  4 NA  3

response = factor(response, levels = rev(c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable")))

as.numeric(response)

#[1]  3  4  4  1 NA  2
```

If you don't want to change the order of the levels in your factor variable, you can do the following:

```
response = factor(response, levels = c("Exceeded Expectations", "Met Expectations", "Did not meet Expectations", "Unacceptable"))

# Convert to numeric with numeric order of factor reversed
5 - as.numeric(response)

#[1]  3  4  4  1 NA  2
```

You can also calculate the number of levels dynamically, in case the number of levels can vary:

```
# Convert to numeric with numeric order of factor reversed
length(unique(na.omit(response))) + 1 - as.numeric(response)
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I just created the factor here to duplicate the factor levels I get from my dataset. In my dataset, when run dataset$columnName, I get the levels as: Levels: Exceeded Expectations Met Expectations Did not meet Expectations Unacceptable  So when I use as.numeric(dataset$columnName), I get the default order 1 2 3 4 and I want to reverse this so that I get 4 3 2 1

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you're trying to do. At the bottom of my answer, you can see that the mapping from category name to numerical value is what you listed in your question.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now. Let me know if my updated answer is what you intended.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Neat and simple logic!! Thanks for your help.